# Click a radio button automatically on page load

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my code

```
jQuery('#choice_1_10_3_1').attr('checked','checked');
```

I want to check this radio button when the page load. I could not found error in console but my code is not working.

It is essential for me to do. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: why not set the attribute in the html? or does the `#choice` change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code will be run after the page is fully loaded.

Try this :

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#choice_1_10_3_1').attr('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: While this may work, you should really be using `prop()` for this as of jQuery 1.6: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Answer (score 0):

It is possibly executing before the DOM is ready to be queried, try this:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#choice_1_10_3_1').attr('checked','checked');
});
```

It might also be that you need to use `.prop('checked', 'checked')` instead of attr. I can never remember!